# Subform won't add new records

Tags: jquery, forms, ms-access-2010, record, subform

In MS Access, I have a form directly from a table and a subform connected to a query. The reason the subform is connected to the query is because I only want the user to add data for the current month and year, not to previous or future month and year.

It works, the data displays for current month, but the problem is that I cannot add new data.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know if I can gather enough information from your question to really understand what your issue is, but it is possible that if you are using a Query or View as the basis for the data in the form that is the reason why you are unable to add records.

Access and other databases only allow you to add records to an unfiltered dataset (eg one where your returning the entire dataset and not a filtered query or a view of two tables).

This is a limitation of the database technology.  Perhaps find another way of preventing your user from inputting incorrect data.